# Map not showing using Android Studio Google Maps Activity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

For some reason I'm not able to see the Map on my Activity.

I don't get any error on the project/console when running the app.

Things that I've done:

- API is Enabled for Google Maps

[image]

- Get the SHA1 fingerprint from debug.keystore

  **5C:9B:D5:7E:CC:42:64:20:24:15:83:8D:AF:AD:AE:2A:8F:F9:75:36**

[image]

- Added the SHA1 fingerprint with package name

**5C:9B:D5:7E:CC:42:64:20:24:15:83:8D:AF:AD:AE:2A:8F:F9:75:36;one.two**
   [image]

- Put the API Key in the manifest

.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBN8bDm6sYpExCtD3pdNwQu49I65OVCieA" />
```

**Take in consideration that all of the generated code was done by using the Google Maps Activity template from Android Studio version 1.2**

Comment: Please follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, you will get the map finally.

Comment: @bijang Thanks for the input. I'm already doing all the steps in the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to my problem**

Company's firewall was preventing my device to call outside.

Tested in another Network, everything is alright.